# Excel VBA to click on a button using getElementbyID failed

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, getelementbyid

I am working on a project to use excel VBA to click open a "more" button on a page to expand the table.

I have been using getElementbyId at the login page and it worked great!

However, when I use the same getElementbyId line to expand the table, it wouldn't click!

Please suggest any way I can overcome this.

Firstly, here is the html that I want to click on, i.e. the first div:

[image]

here's the code:

```
Debug.Print IE.LocationName; IE.LocationURL

Set Buttons = htmlDoc.getElementById("application-DataMigration-manage-component---TaskOverviewDetail--idTaskOverviewDetail--idTableDetail-trigger")

Buttons.Click                 <----doesn't work
Buttons.Children(0).Click      <----doesn't work
Buttons.FireEvent "onclick"     <----doesn't work

htmlDoc.querySelector("#application-DataMigration-manage-component---TaskOverviewDetail--idTaskOverviewDetail--idTableDetail-trigger div").Click    <----doesn't work
```

what's more perplexing is that each one of these htmls contain an ID where I can comfortably use the getElementbyID method, but now after two days of trials I am wondering if it is not a straightforward data-scraping because the getElementbyID work at the login page, but then this could be some kind of table, or parent-child table thingy...

Please guys, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There are typos in your posted code ( these `html...` variables are all different: `htmlintpu2 = ...`, `htmlinpu2.FireEvent`, `htmlinput2.click`)  I assume these are not in your actual code or you would see errors?

Comment: sorry the htmlinput2 is indeed a typo, which I fixed later on, but the important point is it still wont work

Comment: @garbb I am wondering if I have put the id wrongly. I could use the getelementsbytagname but since it has an ID already, I could use the ID.... but it just wont work

Comment: The id in your dom screenshot ends with "triggerText" but the id in your code just ends in "trigger"

Comment: @chiliNUT not the triggertext, note the first html, that's the one that responds to my click... so I think that's the button I need to click instead of the triggertext

Comment: Oh ok. Tbh its hard to follow, those id names are very very long

Comment: @chilliNUT Okay, then perhaps you can let me know the general concept that I need to follow to try to solve this? Or is there any other link/tutorial that I can refer to?